# Trouble loading angular2/testing.js

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm trying to unit test my angular2 app. Simple test pass but when i open developer tools i still get an error that 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined' testing.ts.9:. How should i load the library? So this error will stop showing up?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing Jasmine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
    <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

    <script src="../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/testing.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- #1. add the system.js library -->

<script>
    // #2. Configure systemjs to use the .js extension
    //     for imports from the app folder
    System.config({

        packages: {
            '../app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        }
    });

    // #3. Import the spec file explicitly
    System.import('hero.spec.js')
            .then(window.onload)
            .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This library was not needed. I remove the line with the import and nothing broke. So i guess it was not really needed.

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular2/testing.js"></script>
```